# p:celleditor is not updated after save, require f5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using celleditor when I click edit the column , to get changes reflects i need to refresh the page using f5. I want to change date, so I click edit button then done the changed and pressed save, but changes reflects only when I refresh page.

```
<p:dataTable id="foodTableId" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" var="v" value="#{dashboardBean.myFoodList}" paginator="true"
        rows="#{msg['dashboard.product.mapping.datatable.rows']}" editable="true">
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{dashboardBean.onEdit}" update=":dashboardForm:foodTableId"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dashboardBean.onCancel}" />
            <p:column style="width:100px;" sortBy="#{v.project}" headerText="Project Name">
                <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.project}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText style="width:305px;" value="#{v.project}"/>
                </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:60px;" sortBy="#{v.action}" headerText="Action" id="actionId">
                <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.action}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                <h:selectOneMenu style="width:90px;" value="#{v.action}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Promo Start" itemValue="Promo Start" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Promo End" itemValue="Promo End" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:120px;" sortBy="#{v.promoDate}" headerText="Action Date">
                <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.promoDateString}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                <p:calendar value="#{v.promoDate}" pattern="MMM dd, yyyy" />
                </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
<p:column style="width:50px;" headerText="#{msg['product.label.edit']}" >
                <p:rowEditor/>
            </p:column>
```

bean

```
public String onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    setEditMode(true);
    foodPromoDTO = (FoodPromotionDTO) event.getObject();
    Map<String, Object> sessMap = CommonUtil.getSessionMap();
    SessionDTO sessionDTO = (SessionDTO) sessMap.get(WebConstants.SESSION_DTO);
    String eid=sessionDTO.getUserDetailsDTO().getEid();
    Integer roleCountryId=sessionDTO.getLoggedinUserRoleCountryId();
    getDashboardService().addFoodPromotion(foodPromoDTO, eid, editMode, roleCountryId,sessionDTO.getLoggedinCountryCode());
    return WebConstants.DASHBOARD;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an ajax event for that whene ever the edit is done it will be saved.

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{beanName.onCellEdit}" update="name of 
your component" />
```

You can include this function in your bean to perform operation.

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  
        //Do oepration
    }
```

Comment: I am using onEdit(RowEditEvent event)

Comment: I have added update attribute but still not updating.

Comment: @Surya - Like the answer says, you *have* to use the `CellEditEvent` to hook into your celledit component. Have you done that?